# checking duplicates in email data

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have many records of data for email, now I want to check if I have duplicate names with same mail id and check if duplicate names exist before @ in email . i am trying below approach but not working for me.
also I have NA and blank cells i also want to ignore those.

```
df <- data.frame(EMP.ID = c(88111,"BBB4477","BBB4058","BBB5832","BBB0338","BBB1814","BBB6543",875430,875970,"BBB0243","BBB1943","BBB9344","BBB9701","BBB1814","BBB8648","BBB4373","BBB7270","BBB6165","BBB7460","BBB7528","BBB6092"),
                 name = c("link adam","dy tt","link adam","gbesada","dojeda","slew lang"," alpucheta","r zona","jachaval","allo nyyn","mbautis","grand fring","jali","kintom dang","namoti","shan mig","NA","NA","NA","NA",""),
                 email = c("link.adam@gmail.com","dy.tt@abcd.com","link.adam@gmail.com","gbesada@abcd.com","dojeda@abcd.com"," slew.lang@abcd.com"," alpucheta@abcd.com"," rzona@abcd.com","jachaval@abcd.com","allo@abcd.com","mbautis@abcd.com","grand.fring@abcd.com","jali@abcd.com","kintom.dang@abcd.com","namoti@abcd.com","shan.mig@abcd.com","mbautis@XYZ.com"," slew.lang@abcd.com","","NA",""))

Email= "email"
Name = "name"
valuesToIgnore <- c("", NA)

df <- df %>% mutate(`duplicate mailid` = ifelse(
  duplicated(stringr::str_extract(Email, "([^@]+)")) & 
    !is.na(Email) & 
    nchar(as.character(Email)) > 0, 
  "Duplicate mail exist", ""
))

indicesOfAtSymbol <- unlist(gregexpr(pattern='@',Email))
namesFromEmails <- substr(Email,1, indicesOfAtSymbol-1)
df <- df %>%  mutate(`duplicate name`= ifelse(duplicated(namesFromEmails, incomparables=valuesToIgnore),"duplicate name",""))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tidyverse is a hammer so everything looks like a nail. Hammers are dangerous.

```
df <- data.frame(EMP.ID = c(88111,"BBB4477","BBB4058","BBB5832","BBB0338","BBB1814","BBB6543",875430,875970,"BBB0243","BBB1943","BBB9344","BBB9701","BBB1814","BBB8648","BBB4373","BBB7270","BBB6165","BBB7460","BBB7528","BBB6092"),
                 name = c("link adam","dy tt","link adam","gbesada","dojeda","slew lang"," alpucheta","r zona","jachaval","allo nyyn","mbautis","grand fring","jali","kintom dang","namoti","shan mig","NA","NA","NA","NA",""),
                 email = c("link.adam@gmail.com","dy.tt@abcd.com","link.adam@gmail.com","gbesada@abcd.com","dojeda@abcd.com"," slew.lang@abcd.com"," alpucheta@abcd.com"," rzona@abcd.com","jachaval@abcd.com","allo@abcd.com","mbautis@abcd.com","grand.fring@abcd.com","jali@abcd.com","kintom.dang@abcd.com","namoti@abcd.com","shan.mig@abcd.com","mbautis@XYZ.com"," slew.lang@abcd.com","","NA",""))

parts = strsplit(df$email, "@")
first_parts = character()
for (i in 1:length(parts)) {
  first_parts[i] <- parts[[i]][1]
}
print(parts[which(duplicated(first_parts))])
```

Pure R solution. If you need something else, just use the indexes from the `which(duplicated(first_parts))` to retrieve the data. No need summon the Tidyverse horrors.

Further explanation, as requested in the comment:

1. `strsplit(df$email, "@")` takes the email column from your data frame and separates each string by the "@" sign.
2. `first_parts = character()` creates an empty character vector
3. `for (i in 1:length(parts)) { first_parts[i] <- parts[[i]][1] }` since the strsplit results in a list which is a tad clunky, here we take only the first half of the emails, since that is what we want to compare.
4. `duplicated(first_parts)` returns a boolean vector with true for every value that is encountered for 2nd time.
5. `which(...)` returns indices of the TRUEs. A step that is more of a cosmetic improvement since reading numbers is usually easier than searching for few TRUEs in a long vector of FALSEs.
6. `parts[...]` take only the list entries with the indices from the previous step. Also note that in case that the email prefix occurs 3 or more times, it will be listed here N - 1 times, since the duplicated returns TRUE for each occurence beyond first.

And seriously. If you need to read this explanation, keep away from tidyverse until you learn the basics. Tidyverse is a really powerful tool. That I admit. However it brings further chaos to the already chaotic R so unless you have solid grasp on R, please reconsider.

Comment: i am unable to understand this approach please explain, or if there is any other solution

Comment: i mean i am unable to use it as per my requirement , please help
I have just updated my required output

Comment: this is not a site to help with solving your homework. I gave you solution for the problem - rest is just cosmetics.

Comment: great thanks , i have done it with you code thanks for help again